Assign same value to rows having specific condition using window function in spark scala
I have the dataframe given by :
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+
|id_tech_csi_exposure|projection_method_user||id_tech_csi|id_tech_csi_parent|
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+
|            24996721|                    EC|    24996721|          24996722|
|            24996722|                    MA|    24996722|              null|
|            45526622|                    EC|    45526622|              null|
|            45526650|                    EC|    45526650|              null|
|            45526651|                    EC|    45526651|              null|
|            45526657|                    MA|    45526657|              null|
|            47760032|                   SEP|    47760032|          45526651|
|            47760033|                   SEP|    47760033|          45526651|
|            47760040|                   SEP|    47760040|          45526657|
|            47760044|                    PR|    47760044|          45526650|
|            47931838|                   SEP|    47931838|          45526657|
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+

Note that id_tech_csi_parent is the id parent of a child given by id_tech_csi.
When id_tech_csi_parent is null, then id_tech_csi has the id of parent.
The id_tech_csi_exposure is the primary key having values of id_tech_csi or id_tech_csi_parent.
For each child, I want to inherit the projection_method_user value of the parent.
For example, the parent with the id_tech_csi_parent equals to 45526651 has EC as projection_method_user. So, child 47760032 and 47760033 should have the same and get EC value in parent_code column
In other word the parent_code column should be :
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+-----------+
|id_tech_csi_exposure|projection_method_user||id_tech_csi|id_tech_csi_parent|parent_code|
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+-----------+
|            24996721|                    EC|    24996721|          24996722|         MA|
|            24996722|                    MA|    24996722|              null|         MA|
|            45526622|                    EC|    45526622|              null|         EC|
|            45526650|                    EC|    45526650|              null|         EC|
|            45526651|                    EC|    45526651|              null|         EC|
|            45526657|                    MA|    45526657|              null|         MA|
|            47760032|                   SEP|    47760032|          45526651|         EC|
|            47760033|                   SEP|    47760033|          45526651|         EC|
|            47760040|                   SEP|    47760040|          45526657|         MA|
|            47760044|                    PR|    47760044|          45526650|         EC|
|            47931838|                   SEP|    47931838|          45526657|         MA|
+--------------------+----------------------+------------+------------------+-----------+

I want to compute the parent_code using window, first function of spark and without using jointure to minimize shuffle and get more performance,
I tried many solutions but, it does not get the right result :
val isParentCondition = (col("id_tech_csi_parent").isNull && col("id_tech_csi").isNotNull)
val window = Window.partitionBy("id_tech_csi").orderBy(asc_nulls_first("id_tech_csi_parent"))

df.withColumn(
  "parent_code", 
  first(col("projection_method_user"), ignoreNulls = true).over(window)
)

Any help, please ? Thank you
